# ANTLR4 Parser and Lexer Separatly

Tags: antlr4

Im working on a simple program using ANTLR4, but now I'm trying to have the lexer and the parser in different files, but when I run it, i got a bunch of errors :(

**Errors:**

```
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:6:12: implicit definition of token PLUS in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:7:12: implicit definition of token TIMES in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:8:9: implicit definition of token L_PAR in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:8:17: implicit definition of token R_PAR in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:8:25: implicit definition of token ID in parser
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A lexer interpreter can only be created for a lexer or combined grammar.
        at org.antlr.v4.tool.Grammar.createLexerInterpreter(Grammar.java:1319)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.Interpreter.interp(Interpreter.java:167)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.Interpreter.main(Interpreter.java:277)
```

**My ExprParser.g4:**

```
parser grammar ExprParser;
options { tokenVocab=ExprLexer; }
prog: e EOF ;
e: t eprime ;
eprime:
    '+' t eprime
    |
    ;
t: f tprime ;
tprime:
    '*' f tprime
    |
    ;
f:
    '(' e ')'
    | ID
    ;
```

**My ExprLexer.g4:**

```
lexer grammar ExprLexer;

PLUS   : '+';
TIMES  : '*';
L_PAR  : '(';
R_PAR  : ')';
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ -> skip;
ID     : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
WS     : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

**Command: antlr4-parse ExprParser.g4 prog -gui**
**Input: a+b*c**
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is that you are not calling the tool correctly. You must also include the lexer grammar on the command line because it is a split grammar. `echo 'a+b*c' | antlr4-parse.exe ExprLexer.g4 ExprParser.g4 prog -gui`. The answer below is wrong: you *can* use string literals in the parser grammar. But you can do that as long as there is a corresponding rule for that literal in the lexer grammar. You don't need to use PLUS in place of the literal. But, it's best if you be consistent (use PLUS, or use the literal '+').

Answer (score 0):

Well, the warnings are because for example, your parser rule for `eprime` includes the literal token `'+'`.  But in your lexer, you've correctly create a token for `PLUS`.  You just need to use it.  So use `PLUS` in your *parser* grammar instead of the literal plus sign, and repeat for other explicit tokens in the parser grammar.  All the "implicit definition" warnings will disappear when you've done this.

The idea is to have *NO* explicit tokens in the parser grammar if you're going to use separate grammars.

I'll have to look at the error later...as I don't have ANTLR loaded here right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I still get errors:
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:6:4: implicit definition of token PLUS in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:11:4: implicit definition of token TIMES in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:15:4: implicit definition of token L_PAR in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:15:12: implicit definition of token R_PAR in parser
warning(125): ExprParser.g4:16:6: implicit definition of token ID in parser
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A lexer interpreter can only be created for a lexer or combined grammar.